# How to start bluetooth in Kubuntu 18.04 using a usb dongle

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio, firmware

I just got a bluetooth dongle (Asus BT400) to use with my machine running Kubuntu 18.04 and as i thought, the dongle didn't work out of the box.

On the package, i could also see that the dongle was compatible with Windows versions only, no MacOS nor Linux but before going ahead with the purchase which cost me $12, i researched the net and it looks like this dongle works in Linux, indeed.

Well, after spending 1.30hrs trying to make it work, i could finally connect my devices to Linux through the dongle and thought i could share with the community the procedure that i took to make it work. All that needs to be done is installing a firmware for the usb, install some packages to make the machine recognizable and also to play music through the Bluetooth service.

First, once you plug the Bluetooth usb to the machine, open terminal and run:

`dmesg`

You'll see a list with the applets running on the machine but you'll want to focus on the lines where you see the title as "Bluetooth", something like this but not exactly like it (the below line is for example purposes):

`[    3.404520] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (000.000.000) build 000`

If you see a line on the list showing something like this:

`[    3.404520] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd on /lib/firmware/brcm/ failed to load error -2`

This means that the dongle firmware needs to be installed so the Bluetooth can work as it should. At this moment, it seems that the newest firmware for this bluetooth usb model is the BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd. Fortunately, thanks to a GitHub user called @winterheart we can find that exact firmware file in this link: https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0b05-17cb.hcd

Once you get the file, copy it to this folder: /lib/firmware/brcm/ and reboot.

To confirm if the new firmware is being recognized by the system, run:

`dmesg`

And you should see that that Bluetooth error line mentioned above is not being showed anymore. Next step is to reload the btusb driver, to do that run these commands:

`modprobe -r btusb`

`modprobe btusb`

Now, with the firmware part figured out, some packages need to be installed so the dongle can recognize devices, be recognizable by devices and also play stuff on speakers, headphones etc.

The first package to be installed is called "bluez". To install it, run:

`sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez bluez-tools rfkill`

Then make sure that the Bluetooth device is not blocked, by running:

`sudo rfkill list`

If it is, you can unblock it by running:

`sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

To make sure that the Bluetooth service is active, type:

`sudo service bluetooth start`

Alright, almost there. For this step, i would like to raise a comment to the Kubuntu 18.04 dev team. I installed the full Kubuntu 18.04 OS package with all the default apps for that package and apparently, no Bluetooth manager comes installed by default. There is one though from other distros (Gnome/Ubuntu) that is great called Blueman. That is the best Bluetooth manager that i have tried imo and it would be great to have it added to the Kubuntu 18.04 installer.

Ok, so to install the Bluetooth manager (Blueman), run:

`sudo apt-get install blueman`

On a side note, you can also use the "Discover" app to install the manager. Search for "bluetooth" and the app should show as the fourth app listed from top to bottom. After installing, you should see a Bluetooth icon on the system tray (bottom right).

You can open the Bluetooth Manager by right-clicking the Bluetooth icon on  the bottom right and then clicking on "Devices". It is a very self explanatory app which is the reason why i like it a lot. Click "Search" and you should have a list of the devices. Right-click the device then click "Pair", voi la!

Now, another thing to consider is that if you want to listen to music through the Bluetooth, you might want to get the "Pulse Audio Control" or also known as "Pulse Volume Control". To install it, go to the "Discover" app and type pavucontrol or you can also run:

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Open the Pulse Volume Control app and then change the audio receiver to whatever device you have connected.

Well, that is it! Finally, Bluetooth is installed and running in Kubuntu 18.04. Hope this was helpful. Good luck and thanks.

Comment: Was there a question?  This is a Q&A not a forum

Comment: Well, that is what the title is. That is the question that i faced many times and there are dozens of people questioning the same thing in many different Linux forums, including Q&A ones. My point is that everybody should have access to any info regarding how to use Linux. In this case, why not help Kubuntu users on something that is not so literal as in other OS versions. Peace.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use drivers directly from Asus page you can try [this](https://gist.github.com/ssledz/69b7f7b0438e653c08c155e244fdf7d8)